# How to find optimum parameters for GBR using GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, sklearn-pandas, grid-search

I have `34 samples with 4 inputs and one output` in excel file. I am doing prediction using `gradient boost regressor (GBR)` and I want to find the `optimum parameters` for GBR using `grid search method` from `Sklearn` using `cross validation` to split the data. I have implemented this code to tune the GBR parameters but I got this error below. In fact, this code was for a `classification problem using XGB` and I modified this code to fit my regression problem. Please can you help me to fix this error? is it what I have done correct or not?

The error that I have got:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-4ee3b80c1f07> in <module>()
     23 kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
     24 grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, scoring="neg_log_loss", n_jobs=-1, cv=kfold,verbose=1)
---> 25 grid_result = grid_search.fit(X, label_encoded_y)
     26 # summarize results
     27 print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))

D:\Anconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    637                                   error_score=self.error_score)
    638           for parameters, (train, test) in product(candidate_params,
--> 639                                                    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    640 
    641         # if one choose to see train score, "out" will contain train score info

D:\Anconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
    330                                                              n_samples))
    331 
--> 332         for train, test in super(_BaseKFold, self).split(X, y, groups):
    333             yield train, test
    334 

D:\Anconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
     93         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
     94         indices = np.arange(_num_samples(X))
---> 95         for test_index in self._iter_test_masks(X, y, groups):
     96             train_index = indices[np.logical_not(test_index)]
     97             test_index = indices[test_index]

D:\Anconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in _iter_test_masks(self, X, y, groups)
    632 
    633     def _iter_test_masks(self, X, y=None, groups=None):
--> 634         test_folds = self._make_test_folds(X, y)
    635         for i in range(self.n_splits):
    636             yield test_folds == i

D:\Anconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in _make_test_folds(self, X, y)
    597             raise ValueError("n_splits=%d cannot be greater than the"
    598                              " number of members in each class."
--> 599                              % (self.n_splits))
    600         if self.n_splits > min_groups:
    601             warnings.warn(("The least populated class in y has only %d"

ValueError: n_splits=2 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class.
```

This is below my try

```
# XGB, Tune n_estimators and max_depth
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import matplotlib

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor,GradientBoostingRegressor,
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel

from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
#read data
Data_ini = pd.read_excel('Data - 1 output -Ra-in - Crossvalidation.xlsx').iloc[:,:]  #read data

#encode string class values as integers
label_encoded_y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)
# grid search
model = GradientBoostingRegressor()
n_estimators = [50, 100, 150, 200]
max_depth = [2, 4, 6, 8]
print(max_depth)
param_grid = dict(max_depth=max_depth, n_estimators=n_estimators)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, scoring="neg_log_loss", n_jobs=-1, cv=kfold,verbose=1)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(X, label_encoded_y)
# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
# plot results
scores = numpy.array(means).reshape(len(max_depth), len(n_estimators))
for i, value in enumerate(max_depth):
    pyplot.plot(n_estimators, scores[i], label='depth: ' + str(value))
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.xlabel('n_estimators')
pyplot.ylabel('Log Loss')
pyplot.savefig('n_estimators_vs_max_depth.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you are using `StratifiedKFold` for a regression problem. From its [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html)

> This cross-validation object is a variation of KFold that returns stratified folds. The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class.

You will receive `ValueError` when none of the class (in a regression problem, the target value) has more than one instance. You can reproduce this error by

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
kfold.split(x, y)
```

You won't get this error if you let one of the class to have one more instance

```
x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y[1] = 5

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
kfold.split(x, y)
```

To get your code functions properly, you only need to replace `StratifiedKFold` with `Kfold`.

**EDIT**

Because `neg_log_loss` requires `predict_proba` which is not implemented in `GradientBoostingRegressor`, it cannot be used as a scoring function. Essentially, since you are training a model for regression, use `neg_mean_absolute_error` or other metrics for regression listed [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter)

Comment: I followed your comment and replaced StratifiedKFold with Kfold, but I got this new error "AttributeError: 'GradientBoostingRegressor' object has no attribute 'predict_proba' "

Comment: @SH_IQ ah, I forgot, because you are doing regression, you cannot use `neg_log_loss` for scoring cv. From [this sklearn page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter), you can see to use `neg_log_loss`, `predict_proba ` is required which is not implemented in `GradientBoostingRegressor` as the error implies. For a regression problem, use `neg_mean_absolute_error` instead, and everything works fine.